# discord bot that deletes messages until a specific time on real clock when a command is said

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

When u say #start in the server, if it meets the time requirements from the if statement, it starts the whole message deleting thing. Which is perfect. But i'm trying to make it so that when the real clock reaches a specific time, the bot will stop deleting messages. The program doesn't throw up any errors but the bot continues to delete the messages even after the specific time has been reached. No clue what i'm doing wrong, need help please.

```
hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
day = str(time.strftime("%A"))
minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))

if message.author.id == '258621320898543616':    

    if message.content.startswith("#start"):
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "homework protocol has been inititiated")
        asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        if minute >= 0 and minute < 38:

            await bot.send_message(message.channel, "your task is to do art homework")
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, "you can take a break at 6:00. Ganbatte Tatsu kun!")

        while minute >= 0 and minute < 38:
            msg = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author)
            if msg:
                await bot.delete_message(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `minute` variable is never changed in the "deleting loop" of your code, so once the program enters the loop, it will never exit.

Try updating the variable while you're inside your while loop like so:

```
while minute > 0 and minute <= 38:
    # do stuff
    minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
```

Comment: that works fine except for 1 small problem. It only stops deleting messages after I type in a message on discord. Is there any way for it to automatically exit out of the 'deleting loop' without me having to type in a message after time is up?

Comment: @brandone Add a brief `timeout` to `wait_for_message`